# How to use Infragistics UltraDropDown in Microsoft DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, infragistics

I want to show a Infragistics UltraDropDown control on a particular column of a microsoft DataGridView.

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The control does not implement `IDataGridViewEditingControl`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx.

You could however try to create a control inheriting `UltraDropDown` and implementing the interface, but that's not a trivial thing.

Comment: If using the UltraGrid rather than the DataGridView is an option, then you could use the UltraDropDown as the ValueList for a column in the grid.  There are more details on this in the Infragistics help: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/current/CLR2.0/?page=WinGrid_Using_WinDropDown_inside_WinGrid.html